# How to get all ethereum address list which have my token?

Tags: solidity, web3js, tokens, erc-20, ethereumj

I want a list of all ethereum address which have my ERC20 token in their account. Anyone have an idea how to get list address.  beause i want give divided to each account which have my ERC20 token.

Comment: You can use the events to get the address list or use a new array for storing addresses in your contract.

Comment: From which event I get?

Comment: Do you have a ```Transfer``` event in your contract specifying fromAddress,toAddress,tokenCount params?Can you please paste the code?

Comment: yes i have Transfer and tokenCount

Comment: function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        validateTransfer(msg.sender, _to,_value);
        //assign total sale token count
        if(address(saleToken) == _to) {
            saleToken.setTotalToken(_value);
        }
        return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

Comment: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0xcf6d48ec0a3d695aaf13dd37bc88f1573c1520dd#code

Comment: ..Seems that you have a transfer event```    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);`````

Comment: So list the events in your js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it using your `Transfer` event in your contract.

```
    var myEvent = contract.Transfer({},{fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
    myEvent.get((error, result) => {
               console.log(result);
      });
```

use `fromBlock` param  as `5933218` ,the block in which contract created

Comment: But issues my token contract and ico contract are two different contracts. so i am not getting  Transfer event. do you have any idea about this how get all address?

Comment: @sagarjethi you have to get the instance of token contract in your js and do the above code to fetch the event log.

Comment: contractObj = new web3.eth.Contract(CONTRACT_ABI, contractAddress);

       contractObj.getPastEvents('Transfer' || 'allEvents', {
           fromBlock: 0,
           toBlock: 'latest'
         },function(err,res){
           console.log(err,res);
         });

Comment: contractObj.Transfer({},{ fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' },function(err,res){ console.log(err,res); });